# Error displaying specific database records using find_by (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filter

I am having trouble displaying specific database records in a page. I have a Course model with a :grade column as an integer, and I have created several Courses with different :grade values, and I set up a Grades controller with actions representing each Grade (from 1 - 12) so I can display the courses on separate pages depending on its grade value which was specified in the form while creating a new Course. This is how im trying to achieve this in the Grades Controller:

```
class GradesController < ApplicationController
  def grade1
    @courses = Course.find_by grade: '1'
  end

  def grade2
    @courses = Course.find_by grade: '2'
  end

  .
  .
  .

end
```

The problem is that when I go to that specific Grade's page im getting the following error:

> NoMethodError in Grades#grade8 undefined method `each' for
>   nil:NilClass

What am I doing wrong exactly? How can I only display courses that have a specific valuen on a page?

Comment: `find_by` is only going to return 1 result. In your case, you would need to use `where`. Since it's already in grade controller, you can display the list of course for the grade in `grades#show` if you have the relationship setup. Also, show us the grade8 action where the error occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :grades, only: [] do
   resources :courses, only: [:index], path: "" #-> url.com/grades/:grade_id/courses
end

#app/controllers/courses_controller.rb
class CoursesController < ApplicationController
   def index
      @courses = Course.where grade: params[:grade_id]
   end
end
```

This way, you'll be able to call the following (`url.com/grades/5`):

```
#app/views/courses/index.html.erb
<% @courses.each do |course| %>
   <%= course.title %>
<% end %>
```

---

The main problem you have is that you're expecting `find_by` to return more than one result. As per the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by):

> Finds the **first** record

What you need is [`.where`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where):

```
@courses = Course.where grade: "1"
```

--

The second thing you need to understand is that Ruby is [*object orientated*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming).

This is important because you're calling actions which are super specific:

```
def grade1
```

This is *VERY* bad practice -- it cuts out any extensibility and makes it so that your application can *only* work in the prescribed manner.

The way around this is to use the object-orientated Restful methods built into Rails, namely `show` or `index`:

```
def show
    @courses = Course.where grade: params[:grade_id]
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response, and especially for pointing out that what I was doing was bad practice.